# Adding to active record query based on a condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm getting this error wrong number of arguments (0 for 1+).
My code

```
  vs = where(created_at: start.beginning_of_day..Time.zone.now)
  vs = where(owner_id: id)
  if cat == "store"
    vs = where.not(store_id: 0) 
  end
```

The problem is the if condition there, it doesn't like the way i'm trying to add that condition before executing the where clause.

Is there a way to add that where clause to vs based on if the cat variable is store or not?
Thanks

Comment: I think you mean `vs = vs.where(...)`. Otherwise you're just replacing `vs` with a new scope each time. Maybe this is the whole problem?

Comment: Yeah, I didn't get the point of the multiple declarations either.

Answer (score 0):

No, the problem is not how you add the conditions. It is the condition itself, because `where` needs one parameter. `where.not` does not work at all.

Try `where('store_id <> 0')`

Comment: Unless OP decided to upgrade to Rails 4. Then `where.not` would work.